# Obtener Excepcion cuando un correo no llega a su destinatario por receptor mal escrito o que no exista

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Tengo este codigo

```
public void SendEMail(string recipient, string subject, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                //Intialise Parameters  
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(clientAddress);

                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUser, netPassword);


                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(
                                 senderAddress.Trim(), recipient.Trim());

                mail.From = new MailAddress(senderAddress, "ANONIMOS S,A");
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = message;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                //create Alrternative HTML view
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message, null, "text/html");

                //Add Image
                LinkedResource theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + "images/enacal.png"));
                theEmailImage.ContentId = "myImageID";

                //Add the Image to the Alternate view
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);

                //Add view to the Email Message
                mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Quiero obtener una excepcion, cuando el correo no es enviadoa su destinatario.

He leido que el protocolo SMTP solo se encarga de enviar el correo y no se encarga de recibir respuesta.

Que solución existe para generar un estado de la respuesta del envio? Les agradeceria!!!

Comment: Aqui hay una pregunta similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273949/smtpclient-get-result-from-server-on-send

Comment: Estoy casi convencido que lo que quieres no es posible. Entre otras cosas, los servidores de correo normalmente no devuelven información de si un recipiente de correo no existe, ya que dicha información era utilizada por los spammers para detectar cuentas de correo válidas.

Comment: #Pikoh buen punto ese sobre los spammers, #waimaku Gracias por sus comentarios.